# Prolog: variable instantiation in satisfying a goal

Tags: prolog, variable-assignment

Question arose when reading from *Programming in Prolog* (2003) by Clocksin, Mellish.

Suppose we use lists to map from one sentence to another

```
change(keith, he).
change(very, too).
change(X, X).

alter([], []). 
alter([H|T], [X|Y]) :- change(H, X), alter(T, Y).
```

Could someone elucidate how the variables are instantiated? My book was not particularly in depth on this.

For instance, when using trace:

```
Call: (7) alter([keith, is, very, cool], _G2676) ? creep
Call: (8) change(keith, _G2756) ? creep
Exit: (8) change(keith, he) ? creep
Call: (8) alter([is, very, cool], _G2757) ? creep
Call: (9) change(is, _G2759) ? creep
Exit: (9) change(is, is) ? creep
Call: (9) alter([very, cool], _G2760) ? creep
Call: (10) change(very, _G2762) ? creep
Exit: (10) change(very, too) ? creep
Call: (10) alter([cool], _G2763) ? creep
Call: (11) change(cool, _G2765) ? creep
Exit: (11) change(cool, cool) ? creep
Call: (11) alter([], _G2766) ? creep
Exit: (11) alter([], []) ? creep
Exit: (10) alter([cool], [cool]) ? creep
Exit: (9) alter([very, cool], [too, cool]) ? creep
Exit: (8) alter([is, very, cool], [is, too, cool]) ? creep
Exit: (7) alter([keith, is, very, cool], [he, is, too, cool]) ? creep
B = [he, is, too, cool] .
```

I see several memory address references opened up, as in when alter is encountered in the rule, and recursively paired as:

```
alter([is, very, cool], ???? tail of Z
```

It seems the new Y would take the value of the tail of Z, but since Z is just a reference to a spot on the memory, how are these variables assigned values before returning? Also stemming from this confusion is that I am unable to articulate how the values in the head of the tail, X, in the alter predicate is then able to "build up", as it where, to retain the new values from the change predicate.

Comment: There is no use in talking about memory address references and spots in memory and such (does the book really use such terminology?). The Prolog operational model has variables, unification, pattern matching, and it might be easier if you try to think in such terms.

Comment: `alter([very],[very])` succeeds, intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're bringing a lot of procedural ideas ("baggage") to reading this trace. Let's try and read it with Prolog eyes:

```
Call: (7) alter([keith, is, very, cool], _G2676) ? creep
```

Prolog just restating your goal here. You can ignore the number in the generated variable `_G2676`; it isn't a memory location, the method of generating these variable names varies from implementation and platform, there's no mechanism in Prolog to read an arbitrary memory location, and these generated variable numbers are inaccessible to you in pretty much every sense. It's just an internal bookkeeping thing.

You probably issued a query like this:

```
?- alter([keith, is, very, cool], B).
```

Think about it like this. You're asking Prolog, "prove `alter([keith, is, very, cool], B)` and tell me what B is." So it's going to try to do it.

```
Call: (8) change(keith, _G2756) ? creep
```

What happened here? Prolog looked at your query and saw that you're using `alter/2`. It replaced the *head* of `alter/2` with the *body* of `alter/2`. Quick Prolog anatomy lesson:

```
alter([H|T], [X|Y]) :- change(H, X), alter(T, Y).
-------------------    --------------------------
   "the head"                  "the body"
```

So Prolog said, "to prove `alter([keith,is,very,cool], B)` I must prove `alter([H|T], [X|Y])` with `[keith,is,very,cool]` = `[H|T]` and `B` = `[X|Y]`. (Prolog manages these variable names in the sensible way.) So now Prolog replaces the active query with `change(H, X), alter(T, Y)`. Except, `[H|T]` = `[keith|[is,very,cool]]` and `B` = `[X|Y]`. So what gets printed in the trace is:

```
Call: (8) change(keith, _G2756) ? creep
```

Now Prolog has to take a look at its first clause of `change/2`, which it does, and finds `change(keith, he)`. So Prolog says, "Aha! X = `he`" and then prints:

```
Exit: (8) change(keith, he) ? creep
```

Prolog now says, "OK, I just need to finish that query I started a second ago by looking at the next step in the body of `alter/2`, which is:

```
Call: (8) alter([is, very, cool], _G2757) ? creep
```

Well, just like before, Prolog is now going to replace the `alter/2` query with the body of `alter/2` and try to fulfill it, which means it must now prove:

```
Call: (9) change(is, _G2759) ? creep
```

This one is slightly more interesting, because the first clause of `change/2` does not match. Prolog cannot unify `keith` with `is`, so it fails and moves on to the second clause. It cannot unify `is` with `very`, so it moves on to the third clause and unifies `is` with itself:

```
Exit: (9) change(is, is) ? creep
```

This process repeats, handing very/too and cool/cool, and then Prolog runs out of list constituents and you enter your base case of `alter/2`:

```
Call: (11) alter([], _G2766) ? creep
Exit: (11) alter([], []) ? creep
```

If you're paying attention, you should notice that the query line with the anonymous variable begins `Call:` to signify that Prolog is changing the question, and when Prolog answers the question, the line begins with `Exit:`. There are a few other things a line can begin with that tell you something else about Prolog's execution model: `Retry:` and `Fail:`. But you don't have those here because your query actually works on the first try.

From here out, you just get `Exit` because everything has successfully unified and Prolog is basically done. But this is where the "building up" is happening:

```
Exit: (11) alter([], []) ? creep
Exit: (10) alter([cool], [cool]) ? creep
Exit: (9) alter([very, cool], [too, cool]) ? creep
Exit: (8) alter([is, very, cool], [is, too, cool]) ? creep
Exit: (7) alter([keith, is, very, cool], [he, is, too, cool]) ? creep
```

What's happening here is that `alter([], [])` is proven, so it returns to the outer call (notice the numbers there; they are telling you about the call stack), which means Prolog now has proven that `alter([cool], [cool])` is true, which means it has proven `alter([very, cool], [too, cool])` is true, and so forth. This is just tail recursion working the way one would expect. Finally it outputs that your query succeeded:

```
B = [he, is, too, cool] .
```

So, there's really no memory addresses being opened up here, as you put it.

> It seems the new Y would take the value of the tail of Z, but since Z is just a reference to a spot on the memory, how are these variables assigned values before returning?

In a "normal" programming language, you call a function with some values and you get one value back as a return value. Prolog is not a normal programming languages; you are not defining functions, you are defining relations. A relation is less constrained than a function: sometimes your parameters are inputs and sometimes they are outputs. Variables in Prolog are not "references to spots in memory." They are just names for data; they can be *ground* or *free* depending on whether they have been figured out.

Each step of evaluation in Prolog, Prolog is searching for bindings for the free variables. This is called *unification* and is the fundamental execution model in Prolog. When you issue a query like `change(keith, X)` you are asking Prolog to prove that `change(keith, X)` is true and supply you with the value X that makes it true. Prolog will look at that and come back with `true, X = he`. But you can also ask it `change(X, he)` and Prolog will look at it and say, `true, X = keith`. This is part of what makes it a relation and not a function. You can also say `change(X, Y)` and it will come back with `true, X = keith & Y = he; X = very & Y = too; X = Y` and that multiplicity of results is another way you know you are dealing with relations and not functions.

So in Prolog a variable is not a "spot in memory", it is a binding between a name and a value, and Prolog is able to establish that binding at any step in the evaluation, not just on the way in or during a computation, but on the way out of a successful computation as well!

I bet if you look back in your book, you'll see that it goes into plenty of detail about this. It's one of the best Prolog books out there, and it certainly details this stuff. But I hope this helps anyway!

Comment: Thank you Daniel. It appears I wasn't careful with the idea that the 'outer' Calls were still 'opened' - which funny enough is the entire notion of recursion! I'll reread the beginning of the book.